# ¿Como puedo validar una dirección de domicilio? y que no me deje poner solamente números y letras.Tienen que star los dos tanto letras como numeros

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
let direccion = $("#direccion").val();

const pregdirecc = /^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g;

if (!pregdirecc.test(direccion)) {
                            return Swal.showValidationMessage(`Campo direccion invalido, ingrese correctamente`)
                        }
```

Cuando pogo solamente numeros no me sale el mensaje de error que puedo hacer? todo es java script

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso, te recomiendo crear una función

```js
("#direccion").bind('keypress', function(event) {
  let pregdirecc = new pregdireccExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
  let key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
 }
});
```

Lo anterior sería una forma más ordenada a la hora de hacer tu validación en el  caso que no quieras hacer una función o se te complique, cambia el fragmento que tienes

**/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g**

y pones el que te indiqué en la función

**^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda....pero al momento de poner esta expresion /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/ me sigue pasando de que me deje psar solamente numeros y no me sale el mensaje de error